# WPF Dependency Injection in ValidationRule

Tags: wpf, validation, dependency-injection

Hi I'm currently using Autofac dependency resolver for injecting services into my viewmodels (Using viewmodel locator). I need to do some data validation ([binding validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-binding-validation)) that requires an external service that I'd like to inject into the validation rule:

```
public class ExternalServiceValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    private readonly IValidationService _validationService;

    public ExternalServiceValidationRule (IValidationService validationService)
    {
        _validationService = validationService;
    }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        // simplified code
        return _validationService.Validate(value);
    }
}
```

However I have no idea how to get the injection working with this and can't find anything relevant online.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by implementing the [INotifyDataErrorInfo Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) in my ViewModel base class instead of using the `ValidationRule`. It's a more flexible approach and there are lots of examples out there.